# Проверка пользователя при подключении

Tags: node.js, socket.io, аутентификация, jwt, passport

Есть фронт на `React` есть бек на `nodejs`. Есть регистрация с помощью `passport, jwt`. А также есть `socket-Ы`.

И мне нужно научить приложение проверять на валидность **`юзера`** при подключении и при отправке запросов каждый раз при помощи `jwt`.

Как это сделать и как оно вообще правильно должно быть?

```
io.on('connection', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
  }, function(error, decryptToken, jwtError) {
    if (!error && !jwtError && decryptToken) {
      next(false, {
        username: decryptToken.username,
        id: decryptToken.id
      });
    } else {
      next('guest');
    }
  }))
```

Такая реализация у меня на роуте. Только вместо `socket` `express`.

А вот с `socket` не работает так. Вот как на роуте:

```
router.get('/getusers', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
          session: false
        }), (req, res) => { //реализация });
```

Comment: Мне кажется, это слишком общий вопрос.  Здесь такое не приветствуется. Перефразируйте вопрос. Добавьте код. Покажите Ваши попытки решить проблему. Опишите трудности с которыми столкнулись

Comment: io.on('connection', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function (error, decryptToken, jwtError) {
        if(!error && !jwtError && decryptToken) {
            next(false, {username: decryptToken.username, id: decryptToken.id});
        } else {
            next('guest');
        }
    }))
Такая реализация у меня на роуте. только всесто socket express. А вот с сокет не работает так.

Вот как на роуте: 
router.get('/getusers', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  //реализация
});

Comment: Вы можете самостоятельно добавить код в вопрос. Для этого необходимо нажать "Править"

Comment: Вы в сокете пытаетесь использовать синтаксис Middleware, хотя он его не поддерживает. Попробуйте туже проверку реализовать в теле функции-обработчика.